# How to make regex accept only uppercase and lowercase letters with accents in java?

Tags: java, android, regex

I need only uppercase and lowercase letters with accents,  but the code I use fails.
This is my code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("testTest");

if (matcher.find()){
    tv.setText("true");
}
else{
    tv.setText("false");
}
```

Comment: As expected, the code prints "true"... So please try to explain in detail what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion You get `true`, because regex is focused on finding letters. It would say `false` only, when You test string with no letters at all.
Please consider changing `if else` statement and regex to find out if there are other symbols than letters:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\w]");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("testTest");

if (matcher.find()){
    tv.setText("false");
}
else{
    tv.setText("true");
}
```

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. Now not accept numbers are missing. How can I do this?

Comment: If You need also numbers, lets consider another regex: `^[a-zA-Z\d]+$`