# how to regex accept only uppercase and lowercase with accents?

Tags: java, regex

How to make regular expression for accept only lowercase and uppercase with accents. I try:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("teggR4=$*h");
```

But fails it accept number and other caracteres.

Comment: @R.J actually the question may be duplicate, however text in matcher is different, and that makes this question valid. Yet this could contain a bit more code...

Comment: This could have been edited in this original question, instead of creating a new question. That's why I close voted it, else I wouldn't have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Your regex:
 `^[a-zA-Z]+$` 
Please see Your previous question for different answer: [How to make regex accept only uppercase and lowercase letters with accents in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950477/how-to-make-regex-accept-only-uppercase-and-lowercase-letters-with-accents-in-ja)
Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for my English.  I live in Brazil

Comment: No problem. Everybody just needs some practice, me too. :D